# question on second -> first order systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have heard that it is possible to write second order IVP as first order system.  What are some strategies to writing $y''=xy^2$, $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=2$
 as a first order system $y'=f(y)$, $y(a)=y_0$?  Or perhaps a good tutorial to help me understand this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a second order equation of the form $y''=F(t,y,y')$ as

$$\begin{bmatrix} y' \\ z' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} z \\ F(t,y,z) \end{bmatrix}.$$

Here we just introduce a new variable $z$ to keep track of $y'$, and then the derivative of *that* is the second derivative, which you know from the DE. You can continue in this fashion to deal with higher order ODEs (where, for a single DE of order $n$, you have $n-1$ "bookkeeping" equations and one equation that describes the original DE).

Answer (score 0):

If $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$ then $y''=y'\frac{dy'}{dy}$, giving a first order DE in $y$ and $y'$